# Implementing a timeout while listing files in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement a timeout while listing files in java considering that listing files should be IO bound with some CPU need as well. Following is the code:

FileLister:

```
package com.timeout;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileLister implements Runnable{

private String fileLocation;
private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

public FileLister(String fileLocation){
    this.fileLocation = fileLocation;
}

public void run(){
    this.listFiles(this.fileLocation);
}

public void listFiles(String fileLocation){
    File file = new File(fileLocation);
    File testFile = null;
    String[] fileList = file.list();

    if(null!=fileList){
        for(String fileName:fileList){
            testFile = new File(fileLocation+"/"+fileName);

            if(testFile.isDirectory()){
                listFiles(fileLocation+"/"+fileName);
            }else{
                synchronized(this){
                    this.fileList.add(fileLocation+"/"+fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


public List<String> getFileList() {
    return fileList;
}
}
```

Timer:

```
package com.timeout;

public class Timer implements Runnable{

private long timeout;

public Timer(long timeout){
    this.timeout = timeout;
}

public void run(){

    long expectedEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + this.timeout;
    System.out.println("expectedEndTime---"+expectedEndTime);

    while(System.currentTimeMillis()<expectedEndTime){

    }
    System.out.println("endTime---"+System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.exit(0);

}

}
```

Calling class:

```
package com.timeout;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Timeout {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

    FileLister fl = new FileLister("C:/");
    Timer tm = new Timer(10000);

    Thread flt = new Thread(fl);
    Thread tmt = new Thread(tm);

    flt.start();

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException ie){
        System.exit(0);
    }

    tmt.start();

    System.out.println("Files after 11 second--");
    for(String fileName:fl.getFileList()){
        System.out.println(fileName);
    }

}
}
```

I am putting the timeout as 11 seconds(10+1).

1. This code is giving me a concurrent modification exception. Why should that occur considering only one thread accessing the fileList variable.
2. Considering that listing file is IO Bound will timer work concurrently.

I am not considering TimerTask/Executor as of now.

Comment: Also post the exception details

Answer (score 4):

This does not really make sense if you stick to the old File API, since when you `.listFiles()`, the *whole* directory entries are swallowed into the array that is returned. That you iterate over it afterwards doesn't make the directory entry loading "lazy".

Where is *does* make sense is if you use the new java.nio.file API (Java 7+) -- and you *should* use that and drop `File` --, since [`Files.newDirectoryStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-) *does* lazy load directory entries. (*)

This returns a `DirectoryStream` which is basically a lazy `Iterable` over the directory entries, except that it also implements `Closeable`. And therefore you *can* interrupt this, like in:

```
try (
    final DirectoryStream<Path> entries = Files.newDirectoryStream(...);
) {
    for (final Path entry: entries) {
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            break;
        // proceed with "entry"
    }
}
```

One more reason to use that instead of `.listFiles()`: if the operation to get a `DirectoryStream` fails, you don't get `null` (!!) but an appropriate exception instead: `AccessDeniedException`, `NotDirectoryException`, `NoSuchFileException`, `FileSystemLoopException` (for filesystems with symlink support), etc etc.

Again: ditch `File`.

(*): at least for operating systems which support it (Linux has `getdents()` for instance) or, more generally, for all `FileSystem` implementations which support it

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 threads in your code, file list thread, time out thread and main thread. The while loop executing in time out thread can not block code executing after tmt.start() line. So the fileList ArrayList(not thread safe) is accessed by main thread and file list thread simultaneously, this is why concurrent modification exception caused.